# 'UEFI boot source (windows 8)' and 'Legacy source (RHEL 6)', dual boot issue, after installation

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios, uefi

On new system where windows 8.1 installed already, I have shrieked the partition and tried to install RHEL 6. But the DVD is not detectable (may be because it is not supporting UEFI boot source).

So I have disabled the "Boot Security" option from BIOS and installed RHEL using "Legacy boot source". But the problem is windows 8.1 is NOT get detected when I choose to boot from "Legacy Boot Source". And when I choose "UEFI Boot Source", then only windows 8.1 is detectable.

Now there is only way to switch between OS is to use "Boot Option" (press <kbd>F9</kbd>) every time which does NOT seem a good idea. Is there any other way?

Comment: First Are we dealing with MBR or GPT partitions? Update your question to include this information. Second you are dealing with `UEFI Firmware`not `BIOS`.  The best method would be to use MBR partitions, install both operating systems in legacy mode, if you want both in the boot options.  Additionally [RHEL 6 supports](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-Boot-x86.html) UEFI why did you install in legacy mode in the first place?

Comment: RHEL 6 is already installed

Comment: Its installed but installed it using the leagcy boot options which means it didn't install any of the require efi files. I need to understand the reason you used the legacy boot source options that shouldn't have been required.  I need answer to the questions I asked.

Comment: Tejas stated that the reason for installing in legacy mode was that the computer didn't boot the RHEL6 disc in EFI mode.

Comment: yes NOT booting in EFI mode